# Running Npm install outside client folder is causing corruption?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have this issue where I have a full stack environment node.js/react where I have a client folder named as client. And it has it’s own node modules file , when I want to install a package I just do npm install after I go in to that folder

Project/client/npm install.

Until this point every thing works fine.

Let’s say I want to install a package in on the server environment ,

Project/npm install crypto.

When I do this client node gets corrupted causing problems in the app , unless I do anther npm install in client nothing gets fixed.
Any idea what is the deal here.

Answer (score 1):

You can you `yarn workspace`
Define workspaces in `package.json` like this

```
    },
    "workspaces": [
        "client"
    ]
}
```

For more information, please check here

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/yarn-workspaces-organize-project-codebase-pro/

Comment: Thanks , but , I am pushing npm here, could you please refactor your answer to be npm compatible.

Comment: There's also npm workspace
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces
It is like yarn